# Java program skips over for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, skip

The point of this program is to break down a large array into four separate arrays using recursion until each array contains less than or equal to 1000 integers. When the happens, the arrays will be sorted and then added to an ArrayList.

My problem is that after declaring the four sub-arrays, my program entirely skips over the set of for loops and goes right to the recursive call, which results in my arrays being filled with nothing but zeros. I have no idea why this happens, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public static void quadSort(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
            // Insertion sort
            if(endIndex - startIndex <= 1000) {
                for(int i = 0; i <= endIndex; i++) {
                    int x = array[i];
                    int j = i;
                    while(j > 0 && array[j - 1] > x) {
                        array[j] = array[j - 1];
                        j = j - 1;
                    }
                    array[j] = x;
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    list.add(array[i]);
                }
            }

            else {

                // Split array into four separate arrays
                int[] a = new int[(endIndex + 1) / 4];
                int[] b = new int[(endIndex + 1) / 4];
                int[] c = new int[(endIndex + 1) / 4];
                int[] d = new int[(endIndex + 1) / 4];

                // Fill separate arrays with initial array's values
                for(int i = 0; i < (endIndex + 1) * (1/4); i++) {

                    for(int k = startIndex; k < (endIndex + 1) * (1/4); k++) {
                        a[i] = array[k];
                    }

                    for(int l = (endIndex + 1) * (1/4); l < (endIndex + 1) * (1/2); l++) {
                        b[i] = array[l];
                    }

                    for(int m = (endIndex + 1) * (1/2); m < (endIndex + 1) * (3/4); m++) {
                        c[i] = array[m];
                    }

                    for(int n = (endIndex + 1) * (1/4); n < endIndex + 1; n++) {
                        d[i] = array[n];
                    }
                }

                quadSort(a,0,a.length - 1);
                quadSort(b,0,b.length - 1);
                quadSort(c,0,c.length - 1);
                quadSort(d,0,d.length - 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should be aware of Java's `Integer Arithmetic`. For example, `1/2` or `1/4` evaluates to zero.

Comment: Oh true. I feel like an idiot. I used that to fill my arrays to a quarter size of the original array. Any ideas on a different notation to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: The for loops will also lead to all subarrays elements to be the same.

Comment: Please spell out your *goal*.

Comment: I have int n = {endIndex + 1) * (3/4) to have the for loop start at the third quarter of the list. How would I express that same thing without using division?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `1/4` evaluates to zero (it is an integer division, so the fraction is discarded). You can fix this by multiplying both sides of inequity by 4, like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; 4*i < (endIndex + 1) ; i++)
    ...
```

Now the condition is logically equivalent<sup>*</sup>, but it is evaluated without using division.

<sup>*</sup> Assuming there's no overflow

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < (endIndex + 1) * (1/4); i++)
```

will iterate exactly 0 times, due to the integer division.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of integer arithmetic.

If you run this:

```
 System.out.println(1/4);
```

You get `0`.

On the other hand, this:

```
System.out.println(1.0f/4.0f);
```

gives `0.25`.

---

Using that, you can change your loop to be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (endIndex + 1) * (1.0f/4.0f); i++)
```

Alternatively, you can just skip the division and use a precalculated value instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (endIndex + 1) * .25f; i++)
```